# Umbrella term for paging, sorting and filtering in software

Tags: software, dynamic-verbs

I'm looking to name an object which encapsulates 3 common functionalities used for displaying items on: paging, sorting and filtering. All I'm looking for now is a good name to describe this. I was thinking along the line of 'Pagination', but this seems to be lacking in regard of the filtering and sorting part.

Comment: Could you describe the word paging?

Comment: Is "processing" too generic for your use?

Comment: 'Pagination' is almost always used to mean laying out for printing on pages rather than logical 'paging' through a table of data.

Comment: All questions about naming are out of scope for this site. Please see the [help].

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider [**collate**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/collate)

> To gather and arrange in their proper sequence

That suits sorting and filtering both, though paging perhaps doesn't quite fall under its umbrella explicitly.